# How to upgrade OpenSSL to the latest version in Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

Tags: openvpn, openssl

I was wondering if someone could help with the below:

I am trying to install OpenVPN in mu Ubuntu 20.04 laptop but I get the error: openssl version too old. I run `openssl version` it says is OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020. I have then downloaded and installed openssl-3.0.8 from https://www.openssl.org/source/ but when I check the version, I still get OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020.

I believe I will not be able to install OpenVPN until I don't fix this. Why am I not able to use the latest version of OpenSSL I have installed?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you trying to install openvpn? Did you run `sudo apt install openvpn`?

Comment: Don't download openvpn from somewhere else or add a ppa for it. Install the version from the Ubuntu repos. The approach you are trying will only bring you pain.

Comment: Not an answer as such hence the comment.. It's possible your $PATH is set up such that it still finds the older version first. Try `type -a openssl` and see if there are multiple versions. If there are you can disable something or move them or ..

Answer (score 1):

OpenSSL is included with OpenVPN, so update your version of OpenVPN to the latest for your version of Ubuntu.  I follow the guide [here](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/OpenvpnSoftwareRepos#DebianUbuntu:UsingOpenVPNaptrepositories).

```
sudo -s
curl -fsSL https://swupdate.openvpn.net/repos/repo-public.gpg | gpg --dearmor > /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/openvpn-repo-public.gpg
echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/openvpn-repo-public.gpg] https://build.openvpn.net/debian/openvpn/2.6 focal main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn-aptrepo.list
apt-get update && apt-get install openvpn
```

Comment: True! I see what you meant, and I see what OP wanted, but I think some more info for less-knowledgeable users would be nice. Commands that you suggest certainly may update OpenVPN installation, but they do not "upgrade OpenSSL on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS".  And that would be what the title asked for :)

Answer (score 0):

OpenVPN and ALL dependencies are in the Ubuntu repositories.

You do NOT need to add PPAs or any new sources. You can if you really want to, but then their maintenance and troubleshooting is your responsibility.

Simply `sudo apt install openvpn`

Bolting newer versions of software onto an older Ubuntu system is a classic new-user mistake. Folks who do that might not fully understand how security in Ubuntu works.

The versions of OpenVPN, OpenSSL, and other dependencies in the Ubuntu 20.04 repositories may look old, but don't be fooled by that appearance. Under the hood, they receive the same security patches as newer versions until 2025. It's safe to use.

Comment: While the final paragraph may be technically true, it doesn't mean that the version of OpenSSL isn't "old" -- it's just that it's currently deemed to be "safe". However, there will be much newer versions of OpenSSL available, that may be beneficial for various reasons, but which you can't get simply by using default apt repositories. i.e. With all patches currently applied to an Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS system (June 2023), the version of OpenSSL on the system in `openssl version >  OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020` -- Even though there are much newer versions of OpenSSL available

Comment: @Jon while true that newer packages may be beneficial for some, it's also addressed in the fourth paragraph: Bolting a newer wrong-version package onto an older release of Ubuntu is generally a Bad Idea for non-experts, which the OP seems to be.

Comment: @ user535733 while this may also be true, it doesn't change the fact that said packages, are not, in fact "new" -- they are indeed "old" (by a couple years). It simply just depends on what the needs are, especially when it comes to OpenSSL. As an example, the version of OpenSSL shipped with U20 (1.1.1f) simply will not connect out of the box to some services running default config (such as MS SQL server), and require either openssl.cnf modifications, or an upgrade to a newer version, which will simply not occur via apt upgrades unless a major critical security vulnerability is found in 1.1.1f.

Comment: @Jon are you quibbling about the phrase "*may look old, but don't be fooled by that appearance*?" If so, please offer a better phrasing. I think I understand what you are tried to say twice; I just don't see the relevance to the question that was asked.

Comment: @ user535733 As I said initially, my issue was with the 4th paragraph. If it would have read, "The versions of OpenVPN, OpenSSL, and other dependencies in the Ubuntu 20.04 repositories may be old, but they're still safe to use. The Ubuntu team updates all OS components thru 2025 as required if security vulnerabilities are discovered." The relevance to the question comes in the fact that the user may be looking to update OpenSSL for non-security reasons, such as compatibility or features that are broken in 1.1.1f (the version shipped with U20)